# Intellij idea: How do I create custom Inspection rule with regexp

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I`m looking for a way to create an inspection rule in Intellij that identifies when there are inline comments and moves them to their own line above.

Example: Find

```
someCode() // someComment
```

and replace with

```
// someComment
someCode()
```

I was able to find the correct regexp to find and replace:

> Find: (.*\S.* )(//)(.*\S.*)
>   Replace: $2$3\n$1

But I can`t find a way to make a rule of it.

I have read the documentation on 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-custom-inspections.html
But can`t find any examples that uses regexp for search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp seems to be wrong. It [does not work the way you think](https://regex101.com/r/wL08Kc/1/).

[This one](https://regex101.com/r/5QszsP/1/) should work `^(.*)//(.*)`

However, I'm not completelly sure that you can use it as a custom inspection.

According to [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html). You need to define some structure based on "placeholders". The placeholders [seem to allow regular expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Add_Edit_Highlighting_Pattern.html), but the main structure doesn't seem to do so as it requires an specific syntax.